# Intellij IDEA: создать GUI приложение

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gui

Как в этой замечательной среде создать *GUI* приложение?
Я что-то не могу найти там кнопки/ползунка и т.д. как это есть в том же *Xcode/Visual Studio*. Или *IDEA* не даёт такой возможности?

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html

Comment: плагин JFormDesigner

Comment: что именно у вас не получается? вы можете смело использовать уроки для другой IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В проекте на пакете нажимаете правой кнопкой миши `"New"` `->` `"GUI Form"`.